# Running simple C++ programm using Caffe

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, caffe

I am trying to run my simple program with caffe and i got a error

```
#include <iostream>
#include <caffe/caffe.hpp>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;
using namespace caffe;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    shared_ptr<Net<float> > net_;

    string file_name="it doesn't matter ";

    net_.reset(new Net<float>(file_name, TEST));
// or just: Net<float>     caffe_test_net(file_name, TEST);
}
```

It's built without problem, but when I run program Error: 
symbol lookup error: /home/parrot/eclipse/workspace/Test_Caffe/Debug/Test_Caffe: undefined symbol: _ZN5caffe3NetIfEC1ERKSsNS_5PhaseEPKS1_

I noted that: problem appear when  I use in code caffe::TEST or caffe::TRAIN. I think there are some problem connected to: caffe::Phase. So I can't create caffe::Net , becouse I can't use caffe::TEST.
When i use other class\function... etc from caffe library, There aren't produce this Error.

I use IDE: Eclipse to built project. Some report from console:

make all
Building file: ../src/Test_Caffe.cpp
Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
g++ -I"/home/smilart/0_Intall/1 caffe-rc3/include/" -I/usr/local/cuda-7.5/include/ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/Test_Caffe.d" -MT"src/Test_Caffe.o" -o "src/Test_Caffe.o" "../src/Test_Caffe.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/Test_Caffe.cpp

Building target: Test_Caffe
Invoking: Cross G++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64/ -L"/home/smilart/0_Intall/1 caffe-rc3/build/lib/" -o "Test_Caffe"  ./src/Test_Caffe.o   -lboost_system -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lcudart -lcublas -lcurand -lboost_filesystem -lglog -lprotobuf -lcaffe
Finished building target: Test_Caffe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory `/home/smilart/0_Intall/1 caffe-rc3/build/lib` is not in the standard library search path that the dynamic loader (that loads dynamic libraries) looks in.

There are basiclaly four solutions to this problem:

1. Install the libraries (and headers) into a system directory, one that the system loader looks for libraries in. Then rebuild.
2. Add the directory `/home/smilart/0_Intall/1 caffe-rc3/build/lib` to the path for the loader to look in, by editing `/etc/ld.so.conf`, and run the `ldconfig` program.
3. Modify the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include the `/home/smilart/0_Intall/1 caffe-rc3/build/lib`. Few people recommend this solution though.
4. Modify the build command so that the linker embeds the correct path to the libraries in the executable. This has to be done by adding `-Wl,-rpath,/home/smilart/0_Intall/1 caffe-rc3/build/lib` to the linker command line. This is done somewhere in the Eclipse project settings for the linker.

I recommend the last solution.

Comment: Thank you!!! I tried first 3 solution before post this question, but it's does't help. Also I didn't find the option to add exactly '-Wl,-rpath,/home/smilart/0_Intall/1 caffe-rc3/build/lib'  in the Eclipse (there are several quiet different and they did not help me), So i start  g++ with this option in command line... and it's work!!

Answer (score 0):

Just for another option, you can use nsight - one eclipse version nvidia corporated. Here's some instruction from  caffe offical github: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/IDE---Nvidia%E2%80%99s-Eclipse-Nsight